# Append new row with existing iterate row in CSV file python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I have CSV file Sales_In.csv and DataFrame is:

```
Sales_Region     Dollar_value
East             500
west             500
south            500
North            2000
```

I am Using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import UUID

df= pd.read_csv('Sales_In.csv')
low_sales =df[(df['Dollar_value'] >=500) & (df['Dollar_value']<=1000)]

for index,row in low_sales.iterrows():
    for loop in range(10):
        print(uuid.uuid1().hex[:8],"REP"+str(uuid.uuid4().hex[:9]),row['Sales_Region'])
```

Above code gives me the output like below

```
279418fe HCP6eacac48a East
279418ff HCP6fb7d0ec2 East
27941900 HCP21cb84de3 East
27941901 HCP9b6a34bf0 East
27941902 HCP6aa9f0e20 East
27941903 HCP6fa5e3201 East
27941904 HCPabecf8c42 East
27941905 HCP0922c8acc East
27941906 HCPea9e91d7c East
27941907 HCP95f8dbfb9 East
```

I wanna write this to csv file with headers like below

```
CUS_KEY   Unique Key    Sales_Region
279418fe   HCP6eacac48a  East
279418ff   HCP6fb7d0ec2  East
27941900   HCP21cb84de3  East
...................
```

I am new to python I am kind of stuck in this help me out Thanks!

Comment: Where does `Highly_low` come from? And if you want to write to csv. Use the `pd.DataFrame.to_csv()` func!

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake I have modified my code.

Comment: What about using .. 

`print(uuid.uuid1().hex[:8],"REP"+str(uuid.uuid4().hex[:9]),row['Sales_Region'][['CUS_KEY',   'Unique Key ' ,  'Sales_Region']])`

Comment: @banpd,  see above if  that helps, However , you have shown only two columns in your sample? thats true..

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension for create tuples of values, create `DataFrame` by contructor and last write to file by [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
low_sales =df[(df['Dollar_value'] >=500) & (df['Dollar_value']<=1000)]

L = [(uuid.uuid1().hex[:8],"REP"+str(uuid.uuid4().hex[:9]),x)
      for x in low_sales['Sales_Region'] for i in range(10)]

df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['CUS_KEY','Unique Key','Sales_Region'])
print (df.head(10))
    CUS_KEY    Unique Key Sales_Region
0  96cdb1f8  REPf2fedbce5         East
1  96cdb1f9  REPfc6d311f4         East
2  96cdb1fa  REPa31a28651         East
3  96cdb1fb  REP4f4689565         East
4  96cdb1fc  REP9e0a484a7         East
5  96cdb1fd  REPa8f763796         East
6  96cdb1fe  REP442ad19dd         East
7  96cdb1ff  REPa317fa7b0         East
8  96cdb200  REPb14ca95b9         East
9  96cdb201  REP60c31eb67         East

df.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

If want use your code:

```
L = []
for index,row in low_sales.iterrows():
    for loop in range(10):
        L.append((uuid.uuid1().hex[:8],"REP"+str(uuid.uuid4().hex[:9]),row['Sales_Region']))

df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['CUS_KEY','Unique Key','Sales_Region'])
```

Comment: will it not give error `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'` ?  while  using `low_sales =df[(df['Dollar_value'] >=500) & (df['Dollar_value']<=1000)]`

Comment: @pygo - what is your `Dollar_value` column ? There are numbers?

Comment: @ jezrael , yes, i'm just looking the data frame provided by op.

Answer (score 0):

================================================================

For core python you can use the csv to append new row.
make sure the file.csv will be in right folder

```
import csv
row = ['4', 'Anoop', 'Chamba']

with open('file.csv', 'a') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerow(row)

csvFile.close()
```

======================================================================

In Pandas, below code should resolve your issue:-

```
df = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv")
df['new_column'] = 'some_value'
df.to_csv('myfile.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need this:

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame()
for loop in low_sales.Sales_Region:
    df_2 = df_2.append({'CUS_KEY':uuid.uuid1().hex[:8],
                        'Unique Key':"REP"+str(uuid.uuid4().hex[:9]),
                        'Sales_Region':loop},ignore_index=True)
```

then:

```
df_2.to_csv('New_df.csv', index=False, header=True)
```